# Google cloud server issue of not being live

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have bought a free trial of three months of a google cloud server, I bought a domain from somewhere else. but my website is not being live. Google shows that " this site can not be reached" and I found this "**DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN**". how can I fix my problem?

Comment: You would need to provide more information about what else you did to point the domain name to one of the services in GCP. Just buying a domain won't make the name to be resolved into ip address. Have you configured it to do so? Did you configure it in the same place where you bought the domain or delegated to Cloud DNS in GCP? Did you wait long enough for the changes to propagate (it isn't instantaneous)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign an *A Record* as follows...

- Hostname:Blank or @ as per domain registrar
- Answer/IP:Your Google    Compute's IP
- TTL: normally 3600 (1 hour) seconds but can be set    lower to speed
  things up a bit (you may not be able to set it much    lower than 300
  secs).

Now just wait 4 to 12 hours then it should works.

Answer (score 0):

a) You need to create a [Public Zone in GCP DNS](https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/zones#create-pub-zone)

b) After that, you should delegate the DNS authoritative from your current DNS to GCP Cloud DNS.

Go to where you buy the domain.

b.1) Select your domain.
b.2) Click on the DNS section.
b.3) Select the "Use custom name servers" or similar and updated the fields with the NS provided by the registrar en GCP Cloud DNS when you created the zone name.
This is just an example, the letter could be a,b,c,d,e, and the number 1,2,3,4.
ns-cloud-b1.googledomains.com.
ns-cloud-b2.googledomains.com.
ns-cloud-b3.googledomains.com.
ns-cloud-b4.googledomains.com.

c)Once you have delegated the DNS authoritative to GCP, here check it when you already delegate properly the DNS [1]. The answer must be the NSs above.

[https://www.whatsmydns.net/#NS/"here](https://www.whatsmydns.net/#NS/%22here) your domain"

d) In GCP you need to define a [Firewall Rule allowing access for web browsing](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls#creating_firewall_rules)

Firewall rule for allowing traffic to your VM instance in the corresponding port (usually 80, here a guide for creating a firewall rule.

Use the protocol/port to TCP/80.

e) That's all.

After that, you only need to wait for the full propagation over the internet. It usually takes around 24 hours.

I hope these long instructions help you for reaching the goal.

I hope you have a great day and stay safe!